# PHP mail function sending the email, but not the html form data

Tags: php, html, email, web

The HTML consists of simple input fields as listed in the php below, what happens is PHP mail() sends the email but excludes the form data itself. I have spent a lot of time but not sure why this is happening.

and the php to send the mail:

```
<?php

$to = "user@gmail.com";
$subject = "Question Bank - New Question";
$message = '<html>
        <head>
          <title>New Question</title>
          <style>
            table {
                         border: 1px solid black;
                       }
            table th, tr{
                text-align:center;
            }
          </style>

        </head>
        <body>
          <table cellspacing="20px">
            <tr>
              <th>Username</th>
              <th>Email</th>
              <th>Question</th>
              <th>Question Hint</th>
              <th>Correct Answer</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>'.$_POST["username"].'</td>
              <td>'.$_POST["email"].'</td>
              <td>'.$_POST["question"].'</td>
              <td>'.$_POST["questionhint"].'</td>
              <td>'.$_POST["answer"].'</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </body>
        </html>';

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";


$headers .= 'From:  user@company.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: cc@example.com' . "\r\n";

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
?>
```

Comment: Debug it, do a `var_dump()` and see what's happening

Comment: var_dump() would print all the $_POST values from the HTML form and also receive the email but without the form data.

Comment: _would print_ as in predicting it's result or as in you tried it? you should also `var_dump()` the message and see if it's all good.

Comment: I have tried it..

Comment: That's a good start, now do the `var_dump($message)` and see if the values are there or not.

Comment: yes `var_dump($message)` prints the table as I want in the mail!

Comment: In your inbox, look at your emails source and see if anything is weird there, post the source in your question by editing it.

Comment: source is via tribute.websitewelcome.com, instead of being webmaster@example or something else.

Comment: Which mail client are you using?